# read specific color pixels in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, pixel

I have a framebuffer object bind to a texture,which has black and white pixels spreaded in the texture at different places.I create frame buffer object with respect to new ipad resolution.from this fbo i want to read only white pixels.I would like to know how to do it.I am using glreadpixels function ,which will read all the pixels.But ?I only want white pixels.Please suggest me if there is any way to do this.
I am using OpenGL ES 2.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any OpenGL specific functionality that will do anything like that. You'll just have to stream out the whole buffer and iterate over it on CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need another help, I have a frame buffer object bound to a texture,which is in rgba format.I want to transfer fbo data to cpu,but i want to read only 1byte per pixel.Is it possible to do with glreadpixels in opengl es 2.0.Thanks.